# android webview change navigation bar background color

Tags: android, webview

i don't know if this unique issue, but when webView.loadDataWithBaseURL invoke the navigation bar catch some content from web view.

[image]

the result must be:

[image]

Comment: thanks dude, but its not working, its change first then the problem appear, i was trying also to change the color after the page complete loading and not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is caused by using the webview layerType as LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, forcing the layerType as LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE should resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue. I have been mixing WebViews with regular TextViews in a ScrollView. Setting the LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE on a WebView, produced an error:

```
WebView not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer
```

Setting the parent ScrollView to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

For KitKat versions and above You can try put this code in `onCreate()` method of activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
```